# data-parent="#accordion" not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a scenario where i need to toggle when I click on specific topic and related question list should appear and I also want to closed when one of the collapsible item is shown for that I used accordion.

HTML:

```
 <ul id="accordion">
     <li ng-repeat="topics in oJdDetails.topics" class="topic-li" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="{{'#'+topics + $index}}" data-parent="#accordion" ng-click="fngetQList(topics,$index)">
         <p class="topics-p"> {{topics}}</p>
         <ul id="{{topics + $index}}" class="collapse topic-li">
             <li ng-repeat="value in aQuestionList">{{value.quesList.quesListName}}</li>
         </ul>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.fngetQList = function(topics, index) {
        debugger;
        $scope.displayQList = true;
        $scope.sTopics = topics;
        $scope.index = index;
        getCandidateInterviewListService.fnGetQList(topics).then(function(response) {
            $scope.aQuestionList = response;
            console.log($scope.aQuestionList);
        });
    };
```

Here topics are coming as response and I am making dynamic id for collapse 
but here accordion is not working.

When I click on specific topic the order topic which are opened before are not closed and I don't understand the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't give example here in angular but you can use event "show.bs.collapse" which fire on clicking any accordion, on click you can close those accordion which has class .in and then your clicked accordion will opens. Please see Demo below:

```js
  $('#accordion .collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function (e) {
alert("Open clicked accordian but hide others(already opened)");
        $('#accordion .in').collapse('hide');
    });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading " role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                1
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel body data
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    2
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel body data
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                  3
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="3" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel body data
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```